# Failing to print out contents of a file

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to print out the contents of the file. When I run the program, it doesn't do anything and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = "goog.csv";

    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while(inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data = inputStream.next();
            System.out.println(data + "***");
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you run the program? IDE, Console? Does it print anything when you comment out the content of main and do `System.out.println("Hello World!");`?

Comment: Elaborate on the "does not do anything" part.

Comment: is the file in the same directory? If not, you'll have to put the full path in your string.

Comment: This code works fine for me with a test file.

Comment: Where is "goog.csv" on the file system?

Comment: I run the program in Eclipse. By not doing anything I mean it doesn't print anything to the console in Eclipse. When I drag and drop the file into the same directory, Eclipse keeps automatically putting it in the JRE System Library. But it is also sitting on my desktop. So maybe either I need to use the full path leading to where it is located on my desktop?

Comment: Try running it directly from the console, it looks like you've closed your Eclipse console window or sth similar.

Answer (score 4):

Need to give full path of goog.csv file.
Put ***goog.csv*** file in *workspace .metadata directory*
then give full path of your file it will giving output because i tried your code on my system.
I just change your goog.csv file with mine firmpicture.csv file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = "FilePath";

    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while(inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data = inputStream.next();
            System.out.println(data + "***");
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was starting to get the feeling that either I wasn't putting the file in the right place, or I wasn't locating in correctly.

Comment: @JoshuaOliphant You can put your file anywhere in file system but just need to give full path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path to the file, unless it exists in the present directory.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String a[]) {

       String fileName = "goog.csv";
       File f = new File(fileName);
       String data = "";

       if(f.exists()) {         
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            while((data= br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(!(data.length() == 0))
                    System.out.println(data);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } else {
        System.out.println("The file does not exists !!!");
    }
 }
```